# netstandard support on .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, coreclr

Based on [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) .NET Core support 1.6 version of netstandart.

For .NET Framework it is up to 1.5 (for v4.6.2).

Official .NET Core release version is 1.0.0-preview2-003131, while latest prerelease version is 1.0.0-preview4-004079.

Does this means that both released and prerelease versions fully support netstandart 1.6 or doing it partially? Because implementation is changing all the time and I was not able to find any official link which will confirm that .NET Core 1.0.0-preview2-003131 100% support netstandart 1.6.

I need this to get full API for released and prerelease versions.

Comment: What makes you think that netstandard 1.6 has app-domain? citation? also, .net   core 1.1 has shipped: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/

Comment: Sorry I was looking on netstandart 2.0 by mistake, removed that line.

Comment: As 1380 APIs were added, does that mean netstandart 1.6 was not implemented fully previously or it was supported and those changes are for .NET Standard 1.6.1-preview1 only?

Comment: I don't  want to seem petty, but it is "netstandard", not "netstandart"; netstandard 2.0 is not complete / deployed, so no: you can't use it yet. You'll  just need to use 1.6 or .net core 1.1 for now.

Comment: where is 1380 coming from?  between 1.5 and 1.6, 146 APIs were added. Between 1.6 and 2.0, 19137 APIs were added. It really isn't obvious what you're trying to do here,  and focusing on 1.0.0-preview2-003131  seems moot  since 1.1 has been released...

Comment: I took that number from here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/25/announcing-net-core-1-1-preview-1/

Comment: Actually I just need some official link where I can see that for example .NET Core 1.1 (preview) fully support netstandart 1.6. I need to prepare some report and need official sources.

Comment: @SamvelSiradeghyan https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md is the official docs that show which version of .NET Standard is supported where.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/ also states that .NET Core 1.1 supports .NET Standard 1.6.  You can't get much more explicit than that.

Comment: Daniel das that meen that there is 100% match or it may be say 98%. Can there be at least one type which don't have at least one property which is defined by standart or there is 100% match?

Answer (score 0):

> Official .NET Core release version is 1.0.0-preview2-003131, while latest prerelease version is 1.0.0-preview4-004079.

That's almost wrong. "1.0.0-preview2-003131" is the initial release version for .NET Core SDK, not for .NET Core itself. "1.0.0-preview4-004079" is the latest. Both are in preview as the names indicate.

Well, in your case, it is recommended that you use the latest SDK (preview4), and then you can develop apps that target either .NET Core 1.0 or .NET Core 1.1.

Both .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 are compliant to .NET Standard 1.6. Well, too many names and too many version numbers. You have to carefully digest what they are and what they are made for.

Comment: Thanks for answer and correction if naming. But I have to ask main question again as it wasn't answered. Is there 100% match between standart and API? Or there can be at least one type which don't have at least one property which is defined by standart but will be added on later versions.

Comment: When it is said that "a platform implements a standard", all APIs (100%) in the standard should strictly appear in that platform. If you meet any exception, report to Microsoft as a bug.